# How do i completely remove Avast Antivirus On Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

At first i didn't have antivirus on my Ubuntu 14.04, but a day later my friend sent a email about the antivirus that works on Ubuntu. "Avast" He say, therefore I immediately installed it.

After seeing the results, I was not so happy. I thinks was not as good in Windows. I decided to remove it, but i dont know how?

How to remove it ?

**EDIT**

Using terminal to install it:

```
wget http://files.avast.com/files/linux/avast4workstation_1.0.6-2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i avast4workstation_1.0.6-2_i386.deb
```

(Thanks to Rinzwind for suggestion)

Comment: 1. You answer depends on how you installed it. 2. There is NO NEED for antivirus in Ubuntu -unless- you use Ubuntu as a gateway where there are Windows systems behind it and want to scan incomming mails.

Comment: As long as you don't go rampant running everything as root, you shouldn't need an antivirus. So kickback, relax and enjoy your hassle-free operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall from GUI:

1. Go to *Ubuntu Software Center*
2. Click the **Installed** icon
3. Type `avast` in the searchbox, which is in the upper right corner of the window
4. Click the listed item and click **Remove**

Uninstall from Terminal:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal
2. Type `sudo dpkg -r avast4workstation_1.0.6-2_i386.deb` ,  then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
3. If prompted, type your password then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your password won't be displayed when you type. This is normal. Don't worry.

Comment: `dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in`

Comment: @FirstStrike then try `sudo dpkg -r avast4workstation_1.0.6-2_i386` to see if it works.

Comment: Finally i have remove it, using `sudo dpkg -r avast4workstation` commands. Anyway, thanks for your answer. Your answer helped me

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get purge avast4workstation
```